# Can the schedule program execute on specific seconds?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to create a program that can execute on a specific time every day, but I wonder if there's a way to make this program more precise to execute on specific seconds.

```
import time
import schedule


def func():
    print("ok")


schedule.every().day.at("20:55").do(func)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is pretty simple. You could do something like this:

```
import schedule
import time
import datetime


def func():
    print("Working now")
    print(datetime.datetime.now())

schedule.every().day.at("15:50:15").do(func)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Your `func` will be executed each day at `15:50:15`, where the last number of course indicates the seconds. You can verify it with the second print inside `func`.

Comment: Thanks! LMAO never though it just that easy